# Write QEMU booting virtual machine output to a file

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu

I've been trying out QEMU to play around with some VMs. It's working well, but I keep wanting to be able to view the text (Linux boot process) that quickly scrolls by in the QEMU window on startup of my Linux virtual machine. Is there a way to retrieve this via QEMU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that gets sent to a virtual serial port - this may [need some setup](https://web.archive.org/web/20130209035346/http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Serial/serial-console.html) on the guest OS end.

[try appending `-serial file:FILENAME`](http://www.reactos.org/wiki/QEMU#Redirect_to_a_file) to the command you use to start QEMU.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you.  I ended up appending the following:  -append console=ttyS0,38400 -serial file:serial.out

Comment: The first link is dead